# Melhoria no código

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Olá. Possuo este código:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver  
import time



def visita(link):
    try:    
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(link)
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    driver.close()


links = ['https://link.com/post/6074/','https://link.com/post/6288/']
while True:
        for link in links:
                visita(link)
```

Resumo do código: 
1- Abre os links utilizando o chromedriver 
2- Executa um javascript na página para dar scroll até o final da página, espera 5 segundos e fecha com `driver.close()`


Problema: A execução do código está bastante lenta.

Existe alguma outro módulo/biblioteca que possa fazer o mesmo de uma forma mais eficaz ?

Comment: Tenta melhorar a pergunta, algo como: como posso deixar o meu teste de interface mais rápido de ser executado?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se você esta fazendo um scraping em sites que não requerem autenticação com usuário, ou seja, você não precisa estar logado em uma conta pra ter acesso a esses links, você pode simplesmente utilizar o [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), te poupa muito tempo de execução do que utilizar o Selenium.

Agora como mencionado pelo Roberto, por se tratar do Selenium, a existência de um browser físico aberto na maquina já consome muito tempo, o que voce pode fazer como ele mesmo disse e emular um browser sem a necessidade de abrir um webdriver. Voce pode fazer isso tanto com o [Mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) para python2 quanto com o [MechanicalSoup](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) para python3.

Outra dica que dou, e que por se tratar de vários links, você pode utilizar threads e fazer vários scrapings de uma só vez, agilizando todo o processo. Claro que o tempo de carregamento da pagina ainda continua a mesma coisa, ou se não pior dependendo do seu link de internet.

Comment: E quanto a questão de fazer um scroll até o fim da página ? seria possível com algum destes no qual você citou ?

Comment: A pagina tem aquele chamado infinite scroll (quando você chega no final da pagina, ele carrega novos conteúdos)? Ou todos os itens da pagina são carregados de uma vez? se for um infinite scroll, de um inspect no código da pagina e vá ate a aba network, normalmente o infinite scroll e um request em GET que devolve um JSON como este do Tecmundo ( https://api.tecmundo.com.br/api/v2/news/latest-news/?&older=True&page=3 ) se você mudar o valor do page ele mostra novos conteúdos.

Comment: Seguinte, estou fazendo um bot de visitas pra estes links. São links diferentes para cada usuário, ou seja, se eu visitar um link meu e der scroll até o fim da página isso constará como uma visita, depois do scroll, a página carregará conteúdos de outros usuários. Então eu tenho que visitar meus links, dar o scroll até o fim da página, esperar 5 segundos e então fechar a página para repetir o processo.

Comment: Então recomendo que utilize o Selenium mesmo, pelo que entendi você tem uma lista de links, e você apenas quer acessa-los e dar um scroll ate o fim da pagina e fechar após 5 segundos, tudo isso de forma automatizada. Entendo, o que vc pode fazer e dividir sua task em umas 2-4 threads para agilizar seu processo.

Comment: Se possível, você poderia trazer um exemplo de como rodar meu código em 3 threads? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

"Um pouco" atrasado, mas vou compartilhar pra ajudar pessoas com a mesma dúvida

Ao invés de abrir o driver em cada link, você pode abrir o driver no início do código e ir abrindo os links sem precisar abrir ele de novo.

Ficaria assim

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time

def visita(driver, link):
    try:
        driver.get(link)
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

links = ['https://link.com/post/6074/','https://link.com/post/6288/']

while True:
    for link in links:
            visita(driver, link)
```

Answer (score -2):

Selenium já é lento por natureza pois precisa subir sua aplicação, alguns casos com banco de dados, abrir o Chrome, e navegar, você ainda adicionou para ela ficar 5 segundos esperando que vai deixar todo esse processo 5 segundos mais lento.

Para otimizar você pode usar o PhantomJS ao invés do Selenium, o PhantomJS emula um navegador, e rever a necessidade de esperar 5 segundos para fechar o driver, provavelmente menos de um segundo deve ser suficiente para você.